# Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked on parrotOS

Tags: debian, parrotsec

My parrotOS won’t boot, I didn’t change anything major on my system before this issue happened.  I had nno issues restarting the system previously.  I’m on parrotOS 5.2.

My fstab looks fine and I did not edit it before this issue happened.

Now when I start the computer I get an error in emergency mode:

> >  > Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked. See
> sulogin(8) man page for more details.

Pushing any key just repeats the message, the same thing happens in recovery mode.

I have tried editing fstab(taking out swap and non essential drives) and editing the rescue.service file to try and boot sulogin —force,) but that didn’t work.  I’ve also run fsck that returned 0(no errors).

This is what I tried in the rescue.service

```
ExecStart=-/bin/sh -c "/sbin/sulogin --force; /bin/systemctl --job-mode=fail --no-block default"
```

I think this is related to a Debian bug - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=802211

I found the following documentation but don’t really know what to do with it, how do I set the environment variable $SYSTEMD_SULOGIN_FORCE=1  ?

> systemd-sulogin-shell:
>
> - $SYSTEMD_SULOGIN_FORCE=1 — This skips asking for the root password if the root password is not available (such as when the root account
>   is locked). See sulogin(8) for more details.
>
> 5.2.3.  The rescue boot option is unusable without a root password With the implementation of sulogin used since buster, booting with
> the rescue option always requires the root password. If one has not
> been set, this makes the rescue mode effectively unusable. However it
> is still possible to boot using the kernel
> parameter init=/sbin/sulogin --force To configure systemd to do the
> equivalent of this whenever it boots into rescue mode (also known as
> single mode: see systemd(1)), run sudo systemctl edit
> rescue.service and create a file saying just: [Service]
> Environment=SYSTEMD_SULOGIN_FORCE=1
> It might also (or instead) be useful to do this for the emergency.service unit, which is started automatically in the case
> of certain errors (see systemd.special(7)), or if emergency is added
> to the kernel command line (e.g. if the system can't be recovered by
> using the rescue mode). For background and a discussion on the
> security implications see #802211.

Answer (score 0):

### What to do if you are getting the "Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked... " message

In this situation, the OP would need to try and specify a kernel boot parameter `init="/sbin/sulogin --force"`. Since kernel parameters are normally separated from each other by whitespace, the quotes are probably necessary.

On 2023-May-13, [a patch was applied to `systemd-sulogin-shell`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/fecbce1fc654076a2fc0922e6d36e5300ea04cdf) to allow specifying the `SYSTEMD_SULOGIN_FORCE=1` on the kernel command line too. In other words, if you have a recent enough version of `systemd`, you will be able to use your bootloader to type these options into kernel boot parameters to force the system to give you rescue mode access even if the root account is locked:

```
SYSTEMD_SULOGIN_FORCE=1 init=/sbin/sulogin
```

But if your `systemd` is older than 2023-May-13 this will not work, unless your distribution has specifically backported this patch.

### How to configure `rescue.service` to allow access even if the root account is locked

This is what you can do in advance *when your system still boots normally*.

If you want the system to automatically give you root shell on the console in rescue mode even if the root account is locked or the root password is otherwise unavailable, follow these steps:

Step 1.)

Run `systemctl edit rescue.service` with sudo/as root. This will open an editor that will create a `/etc/systemd/system/rescue.service.d/override.conf` file for you. On older versions of `systemd`, the editor will be initially blank; on newer versions, there will be some descriptive comments and a commented-out version of the existing `rescue.service` definition for your information. In both cases, just type in the following two lines:

```
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_SULOGIN_FORCE=1
```

This method of adding the `SYSTEMD_SULOGIN_FORCE` variable will work on any version of `systemd` that is newer than [2018-Oct-17](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/33eb44fe4a8d7971b5614bc4c2d90f8d91cce66c) or has this patch backported by your distribution.

Depending on your distribution, you might want to apply a similar modification to `emergency.service` too.

Step 2.)

Update your initramfs file. On Debian and related distributions, running `update-initramfs -u -k all` should work. Other distributions use different initramfs generators: on modern RedHat/Fedora and relatives, `dracut -f` should work. On Arch, the command might be `mkinitcpio` but I'm not sure of any options required.

Updating your initramfs ensures the SYSTEMD_SULOGIN_FORCE=1 environment variable will be in effect whenever `rescue.service` is invoked. It might not be strictly necessary in all possible cases, but better safe than sorry.