# Root accout is locked on ParrotOS, need clarification on rescue.service

Tags: root, system-recovery

Aplogies but I'm new Linux user and would appreciate explanation.

The issue is discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/751381/579035).

OP has suggested to set *SYSTEMD_SULOGIN_FORCE=1* using two steps as shown in the ss:

[image: STEPS]

I'm not sure how and where should I run these commands. I chrooted into the locked filesystem from a live .iso but it doesn't work.

I'd appreciate how should I go about this.

Thanks!